# How do I bind a jQuery event to several html IDs in order to grab unique items held within?

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I'm making a hackernews clone and am currently trying to implement the ability to upvote threads and comments. I'm doing this by attaching an ajax request on a click event of the arrow .png file that I'm using in order to increment the threads upvote column in my database.

This shows my index page where I am iterating through each submission.

```
         <% @submissions.each do |submission| %><br>
<div id="upvote" class="submission_upvote/<%= submission.id %>">
    <img src="up.png" />
</div>

<div class="submission">
    <a href="/submissions/<%= submission.id %>">
        <%= submission.id %>. <%= submission.title %> (<a href="<%= submission.url %>"><%= submission.url %></a>)
    </a>
    <p>
        <span id="author_comments_row">by <%= submission.user.name %> <%= submission.created_at %></span>
    </p>
</div>

<%end%>
```

My jquery looks like this at the moment:

```
  $('#upvote img').on('click', function(e){
var num = $('#upvote').attr('class');
var new_num = num.match(/[0-9]/);
```

However, it is only identifying the FIRST instance of the #upvote img. My question is: How do I bind an ajax request to EACH and EVERY '#upvote img' tag so that my i can retrieve the submission ID's?

Comment: Id of element must be unique, so you need to use `upvote` as an class not an id to group all similar elements... then use `$('upvote img').`

Comment: I deleted the ID and called the class to no avail. It is still returning on the first submission's id. I think it has to do with the fact that I am using .attr(); Is there a better method to  use?

Comment: Yeah there is... just a sec I'll make a quick jsfiddle.

Comment: try using event delegation like `$(document).on('click', '.upvote img', function(){...})`

Answer (score 1):

IDs are meant to be unique within a page, so having multiple `#upvote` elements won't fly.  Instead, make it a class, like this:

```
<div class="upvote submission_upvote/<%= submission.id %>">
```

And change your JS to:

```
$('.upvote img').on('click', function(e) { ...
```

edit:

You can also ease your retrieval of the submission id by using a data attribute:

```
<% @submissions.each do |submission| %><br>
  <div class="upvote" data-submission-id="<%= submission.id %>">
    <img src="up.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="submission">
    ...
  </div>
<%end%>
```

So in your JS, you can just:

```
$('.upvote').on('click', function() {
  console.log("submission id: " + $(this).data('submission-id'));
});
```

Play around with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LG3H4/

Comment: Just tried that and it's still returning to me ONLY the first submission ID.
e.g. When I click the 10th upvote arrow, my console still logs that submission ID as 1.

edit: took out attr after first

Comment: See my edit...  Store the data you need in a way that doesn't require parsing it out on the other end.